# Dynamically rename column names in Python

Tags: python, multiple-columns, rename

I am working on a task where I receive several excel files containing similar information. However, every excel sheet has its own column name naming convention, and I have to change the column names in excel manually. Additionally, the columns might get shuffled in the next iteration. So basically, there is no fixed format of the source files currently in place.

Is there any way for automation with Python?

With pandas, I can rename column names with a loop checking with if condition. But again, it's hardcoding. How can this be dynamically handled?

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   # print(col_names[i])
    if df[i] == 'Department':
        df[i] = 'dept'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.rename` method:

```
df.rename({'old_col_name':'new_col_name','old_col_name2':'new_col_name2'},axis=1
```

Comment: This is the method of just renaming the columns. How to do it dynamically based upon the keywords or actual column name

Like DOB/Date of birth  to Date_of_birth

I want to make the column names uniform for every excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.rename` method:

`df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'}, inplace=True)`

If your column indexes remain same, you can also do:

`df.columns = ['newName1', 'newName2']`